# CIN in c++ Stroustrup

Tags: c++

In Stroustrup's book Programming with C++ page 102 he uses `cin` to read in a `double` followed by a `char`, for converting centimetres to inches.

The code he uses:

```
cin >> length >> unit;
```

e.g if the users enters 2.54c.

How does `cin` know to put the 2.54 into `length` and the c into `unit`? I thought there had to be whitespace or an enter key pressed if reading in multiple times?

I'm aware that `cin::getline` is safer but I want to understand why `cin` knows how to switch from `double` to `char`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The conversion goes as far as it can and then stops.

You can try this yourself manually by using `strtod` and tracking the "end" pointer to figure  out how much string you've consumed. The next extraction continues at that point.